# How To Use a Wildcard in robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

Is it possible to:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /apps/abc*/
```

In a robots.txt file to disallow abc123, abc-xyz, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#Universal_.22.2A.22_match):

> The Robot Exclusion Standard does not mention anything about the "*" character in the Disallow: statement. Some crawlers like Googlebot and Slurp recognize strings containing "*", while MSNbot and Teoma interpret it in different ways.

Additional research may be found in the [cited source](http://ghita.org/search-engines-dynamic-content-issues.html).